# Using underscore templates _.template() in asp.net web forms

Tags: javascript, asp.net, backbone.js, webforms, underscore.js

I'm trying to use backbone.js with underscore.js templates in an asp.net web forms application and coming across a problem with the templates.

```
<script id='Template' type='text/template'>
<span class="description <%=Description%>"></span>
</script>
```

This page won't work in asp.net webforms because webforms uses the same <% and %> notation as underscores templates, resulting in an error at runtime

> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Description' does not exist
>   in the current context

Is there a way to get this working in asp.net web forms, or will I have to use a different templating library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override underscore.js template settings. Take a look at _.templateSettings and the documentation (http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template). You can define your own regex for nesting data.

e.g.

```
_.template("hello <?= name ?>", {"name": "Mike"}, {"interpolate": /<?=([\s\S]+?)%>/g) ?>})
```

Comment: yea I just saw this. Seems like a pain, think I'll just use Handlebars.

Comment: @PatrickScott Yeah pretty good idea. I think mustache has been updated too, might be worth looking at

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is not working. This regex seems to match the  pattern.

```
/<\?=([\s\S]+?)>/g
```